# About error in Global.asax.vb

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I was compiling  my asp.net project it was running smoothly. I made some changes in it and its a error saying that

```
Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="LIS.Global_asax" 
             Language="vb" %>
```

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to 
service this request. Please review the following specific parse error 
details and modify your source file appropriately.
```

Parser Error Message: `Could not load type 'LIS.Global_asax'`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to assist anyone in the future (either question or answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems missing the super Class which your global asax inherit, missing reference in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Actually I have deleted asp.net page without excluding from the project that was causing the problem. Now i have exclude that page its working fine for me.

Thanks